# Foreign key inserted in migrations' table in Laravel but there is no migration

Tags: laravel

I try to add a foreign key with the following instruction:

```
$table->foreign('IdUser')->references('Id')->on('Utente')->onDelete('cascade');
```

However when I migrate the table, the message is:

> "Nothing to migrates"

But I already saved the migrations' table

Comment: Did you add that line to an existing migration, or did you create a new one?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you added that line to an existing migration. You will need to create another migration file, reference your table and create the foriegn key. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) in the laravel docs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about implication but you this(Take backup before try it):

**1)** Remove line record from migrations table by batch and drop your table from db
**2)** Copy your migration file into new folder on same lavel(new folder name 'ff')
**3)** Run migrate comman: `php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/ff`

Above steps migrate your table into db with newly added foreign key.

Let me know if there is any concern from above.